# Dynamically Generate Row while user browsing SSAS cube

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I want to generate row dynamically while user browsing the cube.
we can do this using cross join with some unreleated dimension.but here my scenario is different

**Actual Data**

```
Id  amout   item    Fromdate    Todate
1   100 Item-1  1/12/2015   10/12/2015
2   150 Item-1  11/12/2015  NULL
```

**Expected output**

```
Id  amout   item    Date
1   100 Item-1  1/12/2015
1   100 item-1  2/12/2015
1   100 item-1  3/12/2015
1   100 item-1  4/12/2015
1   100 item-1  .
1   100 item-1  .
1   100 item-1  10/12/2015
2   150 Item-1  11/12/2015
2   150 Item-1  12/12/2015
2   150 Item-1  13/12/2015
2   150 Item-1  Up To Today
```

when user browse the cube i want the output like second table.
i don't want to add more rows in to my fact table .i want to do it in my cube it self any help appreciated

Comment: MDX you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the cube. You could do it in a view, and use the view in your cube's datasource.